# Kubernetes rolling update vs set image

Tags: kubernetes

After some intense google and SO search i couldn't find any document that mentions both rolling update and set image, and can stress the difference between the two.

Can anyone shed light? When would I rather use either of those?

EDIT: It's worth mentioning that i'm already working with deployments (rather than replication controller directly) and that I'm using yaml configuration files. It would also be nice to know if there's a way to perform any of those using configuration files rather than direct commands.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `using configuration files rather than direct commands`? You want to deploy conf files on the cluster directly to change a Deployment rather than using the k8s API server?

Comment: I mean that I'm using the second method stated here -> https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/object-management-kubectl/object-management/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In older k8s versions the `ReplicationController` was the only resource to manage a group of replicated pods. To update the pods of a `ReplicationController` you use `kubectl rolling-update`.

Later, k8s introduced the `Deployment` which manages `ReplicaSet` resources. The `Deployment` could be updated via `kubectl set image`.

Working with `Deployment` resources (as you already do) is the preferred way. I guess the `ReplicationController` and its `rolling-update` command are mainly still there for backward compatibility.

---

**UPDATE:** As mentioned in the comments:

To update a `Deployment` I used `kubectl patch` as it could also change things like adding new env vars whereas `kubectl set image` is rather limited and can only change the image version. Also note, that `patch` can be applied to all k8s resources and is not restricted to be used with a `Deployment`.

Later, I shifted my deployment processes to use [helm](https://helm.sh/) - a really neat and k8s native package management tool. Can highly recommend to have a look at it.

Comment: So your'e actually saying i should prefer to use `kubectl set image`? This is also what i took from the docs, but it's very vague in there

Comment: As of writing `Deployments` are more flexible and the way to go. Personally I updated my `Deployments` via `kubectl patch` as it could also change other parts of a deployment like adding new env vars. With `kubectl set image` you can only change the image version. Later I shifted my Deployments to use [helm](https://helm.sh/) - a really neat and k8s native package management tool.